# How can I make a module from the current project available inside of dependency?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'm creating an Elixir library that has some mix tasks. The library is specified as a dependency of :my_app (a Phoenix app). Within the library's mix tasks I want to be able to call `MyApp.Repo.all` however I get an error saying: `** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: MyApp.Repo.all/1 (module MyApp.Repo is not available)` How can I load the MyApp.Repo module without specifying :my_app as a dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have these two setup in your module?

```
use Ecto.Model
import Ecto.Query
```

Comment: Here's a great post on using Repo.all http://blog.drewolson.org/composable-queries-ecto/

Comment: Yes, in Phoenix, these are set up for you in `web/web.ex` and when you generate a model, it uses `web`.